# Animate style properties for group of shapes in KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Is there a shortcut for animating the styles (stroke, fill) for a bunch of shapes at once, or do I need to just loop over the individual shapes and update them one at a time? I tried setting styles at the group level, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's no group level `set` method.

On each animation frame, iterate through the children of your group and use `setFill()` and `setColor()`.

```
var myAnimation= new Kinetic.Animation( changeColors, myLayer );

myAnimation.start();

function changeColors(){

    var children = myKineticGroup.getChildren(); // get children of group

    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
        children[i].setFill("blue");
        children[i].setStroke("red");
    }
}
```